Send notification on multiple device ids with firebase's FCM facility in new version 1
In the past, there was a parameter to pass multiple device ids (registration_ids) to send notification in Android devices. But since the old version of FCM API is deprecated and new FCM API v1 available, how to pass multiple device ids in the api now?
$notification = json_encode([
    "message" => [
         "token" => $myDeviceId, //this is single but I want to pass an array to send notification to specific multiple devices
         "notification" => [
             "body" => $data['description'],
             "title" => $data['title'],
         ],
         "android" => [
             "priority" => "HIGH",
         ],
     ]
]);


There is no way to pass an array of tokens anymore. You'll need to make a separate request for each token, and use HTTP/2 multiplexing to re-use the connection. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/76563436, https://stackoverflow.com/q/76899435

In new version they dont provide the feature to send notification on multiple devices so you have to add for loop for that. Below is the payload difference for iOS and Android :
$data = [
            'message' => [
                'token' => $deviceToken,
                'notification' => [
                    'title' => $title,
                    'body' => $body,
                ],
            ]
        ];
if ($platform === 'android') {
            $data['message']['android'] = [
                'priority' => 'high',
                'notification' => [
                    'title' => $title,
                    'body' => $body,
                    'icon' => 'myIcon',
                    'sound' => 'mySound'
                ]
            ];
        } elseif ($platform === 'ios') {
            $data['message']['apns'] = [
                
                'payload' => [
                    'aps' => [
                        'alert' => [
                            'title' => $title,
                            'body' => $body
                        ],
                        'badge' => 1,
                        'sound' => 'default'
                    ]
                ]
            ];
        }

